# How do I build a summary by joining to a single table with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which is update has some fields with repeating data. I want to roll up this data to summarize it. How do I do this for SQL Server? I have an example of the output and structure below. I've tried some different joins but I've seen repeating data and some errors that I don't understand.

Table structure

- Logfile name (string)
- Status (int) - could be 1, 2, 3 depending on app input

Data

```
f1, 3, 0
f1, 2, 1
f1, 3, 0
f2, 1, 1
f2, 1, 1
f2, 2, 1
....
```

Output

```
File | Count of status == 1 | Count of status == 2 
f1   | 59                  | 43
f2   | 28                  | 99
f3   | 23                  | 16
```

Comment: Why does your data have 3 columns, but you only tell us about two (logfile and status)?

Comment: @David B - because it is a count of each distinct status type.  So if he had 'n' statuses the count of columns would be n+1 (the +1 refers to the file name). Also known as a matrix.

Comment: -1 for dynamically generated database design.

Comment: Omitting the description for the 3rd column doesn't deserve a -1. The question is clear. @JonH, David B was talking about the data, while your comment was about the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize data using rollup:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

What version of sql server are you using ?

If you dont have want to use rollup this should help:

```
SELECT
      FileName,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOf1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOf2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOf3
FROM
      MyTable
GROUP BY FileName
ORDER BY FileName
```

Comment: Not wrong, but only works for statically determined status values.

Comment: That's true. I have this mania of always searching for the most generic answer possible. Did not downvote you, though

Comment: I am pretty sure rollup doesn't apply here. And ORDER BY should come after GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or above, here is the code:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName(cast([status] as varchar))
                        FROM LogTable FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') 


SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT UserIndex,  [status]
       FROM LogTable ) base
       PIVOT (Count(status) FOR [status]
       IN (' + @cols + ')) AS finalpivot'

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```

This will work no matter how many different status you have. It dynamically assembles a query with `PIVOT`.

**Update**

As @JonH pointed out, there was a vulnerability in the code I posted, which made possible an injection attack. This is now fixed, by using [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) when forming the column names.

Other examples:

- [SQL Server PIVOT perhaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182106/sql-server-pivot-perhaps/7182489#7182489)
- [Pivot data in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232593/pivot-data-in-t-sql/7232755#7232755)

Comment: Give it a try. Reporting was never the same since I learned this trick.

Comment: isn't it annoying when the 'best' script is chosen after 4 minutes ? Nice dynamic script. +1. Here is a way to improve it slightly SELECT @cols = coalesce(@cols + ',', '') + '[' + cast([status] as varchar)
+ ']' FROM (select distinct status from @logtable) a order by status

Comment: @Adrian - One thing I see about this is it is vulnerable to an injection attack.  Don't concatenate your square brackets around the column name to avoid this.  You could use QUOTENAME to return a unicode string.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @JonH. I just updated the code to make it more injection-proof.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    file,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count of status == 1] ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count of status == 2] 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY file 
ORDER BY file
```

Comment: Approach not wrong, but only works for statically determined status values.

Comment: @Jonh, "Group by comes after order by"? You are kidding, right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499%28v=sql.90%29.aspx