# SQL Server PIVOT perhaps?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

`SELECT Name1, Name2, Value FROM mytable` gives me the following result set:

```
Name1 Name2 Value
A     P1     1
A     P2     1
A     P3     2
B     P1     3
B     P2     1
B     P4     1
```

How do I translate that to:

```
       A     B
P1     1     4
P2     1     1
P3     2     null
P4     null  1
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @user!  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are A and B a fixed list of constants?

Comment: @jadarnel27 - There's a hint in the title of the question ;)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005. Sure there is a hint, but I don't know how to pivot it which is why I asked :)

Comment: @Tony Oh my, isn't my face red =)  I just looked at the tags

Comment: A and B are not fixed, the top select could return more than just A and B, sometimes it will be A, B, C, ... X for instance.

Comment: @jadarnel27 wasn't your fault, the question wasn't tagged with [tag:sql-server-2005] until Tony edited it, and just because the OP happened to use the keyword `PIVOT` doesn't necessarily mean they know it's only available in 2005+. Lots of people ask HOW DO I PIVOT THIS? when they're using SQL Server 2000. :-)

Comment: @user683302 I think that's important information that should be part of the question - it's not clear that there may be other values other than `A` and `B`. Also what happens when there are two rows like this: `A, P1, 1` and `A, P1, 4`? Detailing the unique constraints on the table will help others determine how to aggregate if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) clause. Your query could be something like this:

```
WITH Source as (
    SELECT Name1, Name2, [Value]
    FROM mytable 
)

SELECT Name2, CASE WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN A ELSE 'your string' END As A
, CASE WHEN B IS NOT NULL THEN B ELSE 'your string' END As B
FROM (
        SELECT Name2, Name1, [Value]
        FROM Source
) s
PIVOT 
(
    MAX([Value]) FOR Name1 IN (A, B) -- any other Name1 would go here
) p
```

using your sample data above, my results were

```
P1  1           3
P2  1           1
P3  2           your string
P4  your string 1
```

EDIT:

Since you have an unknown number of columns, you will need to look at using dynamic SQL and there are several answers here on SO about that with PIVOT.

[SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)

[Pivot Table and Concatenate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns-sql-problem)

Comment: The issue is the OP cannot limit the output to A, B. There may also be C, ..., X, as he stated in one of the comments.

Comment: I made a few modifications and was able to get it to work by using this example and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns-sql-problem#159803. One last thing, how would I go about replacing the NULLs with another String. I tried a CASE but it only replaces the 'Value' fields that have values, not the NULLs

Comment: I updated the above PIVOT query using CASE and is changes the NUll values to a string.

Comment: I would prefer COALESCE over CASE in this situation, otherwise it's nice.

Comment: @Andriy I use COALESCE too in a lot of situations.  I have gotten flack for using it on here before so I used CASE this time.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005, here is the code:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName([Name1])
                        FROM myTable FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') 


SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT Name2, Name1, Value
       FROM myTable ) base
       PIVOT (Sum(Value) FOR [Name1]
       IN (' + @cols + ')) AS finalpivot'

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```

This will work no matter how many different status you have. It dynamically assembles a query with `PIVOT`. The only way you can do PIVOT with dynamic columns is by assembling the the query dynamically, which can be done in SQL Server.

Other examples:

- [Pivot data in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232593/pivot-data-in-t-sql/7232755#7232755)
- [How do I build a summary by joining to a single table with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849678/how-do-i-build-a-summary-by-joining-to-a-single-table-with-sql-server/6849795#6849795)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/8248059/570191

Comment: @Martin It avoids injection attacks!

Comment: This resembled a post similiar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849678/how-do-i-build-a-summary-by-joining-to-a-single-table-with-sql-server/6849795#6849795 in fact the injection attack I mentioned :).

Answer (score 4):

I don't have SQL Server running here at work so this may not by completely syntatically correct but one approach would be cross tabulation

```
SELECT name2
     , SUM(CASE WHEN name1 = 'A' THEN value END) AS A
     , SUM(CASE WHEN name1 = 'B' THEN value END) AS B
FROM table
GROUP BY name2
```

For variable number of columns you could use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql+',','') + 'SUM(CASE WHEN nane1 = '''+name1+''' THEN value END) AS ['+name1']' FROM table

SET @sql = 'SELECT name2, '+@sql+' FROM table GROUP BY name2'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: There are much [more constructive](http://xkcd.com/303/) things you can do while your code is compiling ;)  I posted that comment while I was at work as well haha