# How do I achieve transposing of rows into columns in MS SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

Departments --< Employees

Department table has data such as:

```
id, Name
1, Marketing
2, Sales
```

Employees table has data such as:

```
id, Name, DepartmentId, RatePerDay
1, Alex,1, 40
2, Bob,1, 30
3, Calvin,1, 40
4, Dal,1, 30
```

I want to get two data sets back as follows for each department:

```
DepartmentName, Employee1,Employee12,Employee13,Employee14
Marketing, Alex, Bob, Calvin, Dal

DepartmentName, RatePerDay1, RatePerDay2, RatePerDay3, RatePerDay4
Marketing, 40,30,40,30
```

I have to write a MS SQL 2008 Stored procedure which achieves this result?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: there are a lot of the same questions `rows to columns tsql`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT perhaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182106/sql-server-pivot-perhaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, First take a look at [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), since you are gonna need dynamic SQL. Then you can try the following:

```
DECLARE @EmployeesId VARCHAR(MAX), @EmployeesIdAlias VARCHAR(MAX), @Query1 VARCHAR(MAX), @Query2 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Rates VARCHAR(MAX), @RatesAlias VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @EmployeesId = ISNULL(@EmployeesId + ',', '') + '[' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']',
        @EmployeesIdAlias = ISNULL(@EmployeesIdAlias + ',', '') + '[' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] AS [Employee ' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']',
        @RatesAlias = ISNULL(@RatesAlias + ',', '') + '[' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] AS [Rate ' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'
FROM Employees


SET @Query1 = '
SELECT Department, '+@EmployeesIdAlias+'
FROM (  SELECT A.Id, A.Name, B.Name Department
        FROM Employees A
        INNER JOIN Department B
        ON A.DepartmentId = B.Id) Source
PIVOT(MIN(Name) FOR Id IN ('+@EmployeesId+')) AS PT'

EXEC(@Query1)

SET @Query2 = '
SELECT Department, '+@RatesAlias+'
FROM (  SELECT A.Id, A.RatePerDay, B.Name Department
        FROM Employees A
        INNER JOIN Department B
        ON A.DepartmentId = B.Id) Source
PIVOT(MIN(RatePerDay) FOR Id IN ('+@EmployeesId+')) AS PT'

EXEC(@Query2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pivot may work for what your doing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=PIVOTData