# Table merge to itself

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I created a table "Test"

```
create table test
(
  id int identity(1,1) not null,
  correlation int,
  data varchar(max)
)
```

Below are data of the table

```
insert into test(correlation,data) values(1,'x0')
insert into test(correlation,data) values(1,'x1')
insert into test(correlation,data) values(2,'z1')
insert into test(correlation,data) values(2,'z2')
insert into test(correlation,data) values(3,'a')
insert into test(correlation,data) values(4,'b')
insert into test(correlation,data) values(5,'c')
```

I need to display data on the web page and to connect table to itself on
correlation and to do paging

For example if I have two records with the same correlation (1) I need to 
display two rows as one row with the data as Current Data and Previous Data.
In example below current data will be x1 and previous will be x0.

Before

```
 Correlation  Data
    1         x0    
    1         x1
```

After

```
Correlation     Previous Data   Current Data
1                  xo             x1
```

If correlation has only one row , than previous correlation in result will be null.

Currenly I did paging in Linq and it's working but I am afraid that in future it will cost
performance problem.

Can sameone can help me with SQL .

Is there other good solution for this problem.

Comment: So each `Correlation` has just two `data` entries the first will be `Previous` and the second will be `Current` ?? and What about the correlations that have only one `data` entry??

Comment: If correlation have only one data entry than Current will be with value and previous will be null

Comment: You want to pivot data on your correlation data. (PIvot is the function your looking for several EXAMPLES can be found though search)  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182106/sql-server-pivot-perhaps

Comment: @xQbert, But pivot it is about turning the unique values from one column to be a headers for new columns, but in this case how this would be applied???

Comment: I considered  pivot table . But this will not mach here

Comment: Fair enough: How do I know what data is previous and what data is current then?  or does it matter..  Looking at 3 a.. how do I know it's Previous or "current"?  Do I assume 1 entry means previous or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with C as
(
  select correlation,
         data,
         row_number() over(partition by correlation order by id desc) as rn
  from @test
  where SomeColumn > 10 -- Where clause goes here (if possible)
)  
select C1.correlation,
       C2.data as [Previous Data],
       C1.data as [Current Data]
from C as C1
  left outer join C as C2 
    on C1.correlation = C2.correlation and
       C2.rn = 2
where C1.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
correlation Previous Data Current Data
----------- ------------- ------------
1           x0            x1
2           z1            z2
3           NULL          a
4           NULL          b
5           NULL          c
```

Comment: @GregoryNozik - I was a bit quick to post. Updated answer. Test here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119042/

Comment: In real live my test table is composes from many tables. Do you think it will work fast ?

Comment: @GregoryNozik - Speed of a query is dependent on a lot of stuff, indexes and how much data you have for instance. If you have anything that filters the data you want, you should preferably put the where clause in the CTE part to avoid ranking on rows you actually don't need.

Comment: `C` is a CTE. I will add a where clause where it will do most good :)

Comment: Could you helped me to optimized this query

Comment: @GregoryNozik - You should put that out as a new question giving all a chance to help. Provide the query with table structure including existing indexes and expected number of rows in the table. Describe also what performance you have and what performance you need.