# Pivot data in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a group of people. Lets call them A,B,C. I have a table that shows how much they were paid each month....

```
PERSON|MONTH|PAID
A      JAN   10
A      FEB   20   
B      JAN   10   
B      FEB   20   
B      SEP   30   
C      JAN   10   
C      JUNE  20   
C      JULY  30   
C      SEP   40
```

THIS table can and does go on for years and years..

Is there a way to pivot this table (nothing as I see really needs to be aggregated which is usually done in pivots) In a table that looks like the following?

```
     JAN    FEB    MAR    APR    MAY    JUN    JUL    AGU    SEP
A    10     20
B    10     20     -      -      -      -      -      -      30
C    10     -      -      -      -      20     30     -      40
```

Haven't run into something like this before but assume it is a common problem any ideas?

Comment: You can still "aggregate" on `MONTH`. It's just that in your data set it's already aggregated. Just use something like `SUM`.

Comment: you can do this for fixed number of columns,Jan..Feb... ,you cannot do this for variable no of columns

Comment: ...No way to do this for variable columns?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with dynamic # of columns, if you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 (or above), here is the code:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName([Month])
                        FROM YourTable FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') 


SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT Person, Month, Paid
       FROM YourTable ) base
       PIVOT (Sum(Paid) FOR [Person]
       IN (' + @cols + ')) AS finalpivot'

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```

This will work no matter how many different status you have. It dynamically assembles a query with `PIVOT`. The only way you can do PIVOT with dynamic columns is by assembling the the query dynamically, which can be done in SQL Server.

Other examples:

- [SQL Server PIVOT perhaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182106/sql-server-pivot-perhaps/7182489#7182489)
- [How do I build a summary by joining to a single table with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849678/how-do-i-build-a-summary-by-joining-to-a-single-table-with-sql-server/6849795#6849795)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you need a dynamic # of columns, since there are always 12 months in a year. Also your month names seem a bit inconsistent in length.

Sample result set:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'A' [PERSON],'JAN' [MONTH],'10' [PAID]
UNION SELECT 'A','FEB',20
UNION SELECT 'B','JAN',10
UNION SELECT 'B','FEB',20
UNION SELECT 'B','SEP',30
UNION SELECT 'C','JAN',10
UNION SELECT 'C','JUNE',20
UNION SELECT 'C','JULY',30
UNION SELECT 'C','SEP',40) AS A
PIVOT (SUM([PAID]) FOR [MONTH] IN ([JAN],[FEB],[MARCH],[APRIL],[MAY],[JUNE],[JULY],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC])) p
```

Against your table this would become:

```
SELECT [PERSON],[MONTH],[PAID]
FROM [YOURTABLE]
PIVOT (SUM([PAID]) FOR [MONTH] IN ([JAN],[FEB],[MARCH],[APRIL],[MAY],[JUNE],[JULY],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC])) p
```

If you add a year column it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'A' [PERSON],'JAN' [MONTH],'10' [PAID], 2011 [YEAR]
UNION SELECT 'A','FEB',20, 2011
UNION SELECT 'B','JAN',10, 2011
UNION SELECT 'A','FEB',20, 2010
UNION SELECT 'B','JAN',10, 2010
UNION SELECT 'B','FEB',20,2011
UNION SELECT 'B','SEP',30,2011
UNION SELECT 'C','JAN',10,2011
UNION SELECT 'C','JUNE',20,2011
UNION SELECT 'C','JULY',30,2011
UNION SELECT 'C','SEP',40,2011) AS A
PIVOT (SUM([PAID]) FOR [MONTH] IN ([JAN],[FEB],[MARCH],[APRIL],[MAY],[JUNE],[JULY],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC])) p
```

Comment: Need dynamic column because we dont want to write the months in for each year over and over again

Comment: There is no reason you have to if [YEAR] is a fixed column. See my third example.