# Sql Server Pivot with lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I've looked through most of the pivot table examples, but I haven't found quite the same scenario yet (plus, I'm probably out of my league with this).

I have an Employees table, an Attributes table, and a lookup table that matches employees and attributes:

```
dbo.Employees
employee_ID INT
employee_name NVARCHAR(50)
```

```
employee_ID | employee_name 
1           | Joe Smith
2           | Don Johnson
```

```
dbo.Attributes
attribute_ID INT
attribute_description NVARCHAR(50)
```

```
attribute_ID | attribute_description
50           | Works Weekends
55           | Wears Hats
61           | Enjoys Baseball
```

```
dbo.EmployeeAttributes
employee_attribute_ID INT
employee_ID_fk INT
attribute_ID_fk INT
```

```
employee_attribute_ID | employee_ID_fk | attribute_ID_fk
20                    | 1              | 50
21                    | 2              | 61
22                    | 2              | 55
```

I'm trying to end up with a result set where the attributes are displayed as columns, with boolean values indicating whether the attribute is present for a given employee, like:

```
employee_ID | employee_name | Works Weekends | Wears Hats | Enjoys Baseball
1           | Joe Smith     | 1              | 0          | 1
2           | Don Johnson   | 0              | 1          | 0
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: i've got a blog on this subject [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-unpivot-and-pivot). let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of out of time right now, but couldn't help giving you some pointers.:

1. Assemble your basic (non pivot) query. You should use a couple of `LEFT JOIN` between your tables. Once you have that, proceed to Pivoting.
2. Look at the stuff I've written on Dynamic PIVOT:

   - [SQL Server PIVOT perhaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182106/sql-server-pivot-perhaps/7182489#7182489)
   - [Pivot data in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232593/pivot-data-in-t-sql/7232755#7232755)
   - [How do I build a summary by joining to a single table with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849678/how-do-i-build-a-summary-by-joining-to-a-single-table-with-sql-server/6849795#6849795)

Comment: Thanks Adrian - this put me on the right track.  Any ideas how to add a case statement to change nulls to 0 and values to 1?

Comment: Yes: `case when YourValue is null then 0 else 1 end`

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'where' to add the case statement.  If I add it to the select statement, it doesn't catch the nulls.