# Pivoting the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my SQL statement

```
select  id , name, type,  value  from table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id
where  b.type in ('display','contact','ship')
```

which produces below result

```
ID  name     type           value
5   test     display        display1
5   test     contact        contact1
5   test     ship           ship1
6   test2    display        display2
6   test2    contact        contact2
6   test2    ship           ship2
```

I need to get result in kind of pivoted format like this

```
id  name   display   contact   ship
5   test   display1  contact1 ship1
6   test2  display2  contact2 ship2
```

I tried this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849706/2645738 ,but its giving me the same result (3 rows for each data). It's like i need to group by id and name,but don't know how to make display,contact,ship as columns.

Would you please help me for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want:

```
select  a.id , a.name, 
        max(case when b.type = 'display' then value end) as display,
        max(case when b.type = 'contact' then value end) as contact,
        max(case when b.type = 'ship' then value end) as ship
from table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id
where  b.type in ('display','contact','ship')
group by a.id, a.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. This worked. Can you change this in such a way that display,contact and ship are in one variable as comma separated values? e.g. DECLARE @Types varchar(max) = 'display,contact,ship'. I will be writing this code in stored procedure and this values may come in a single variable.

Answer (score 4):

It is necessary to use `PIVOT` you could also do that by using simple `case` expression

```
SELECT ID,
      Name,
       MAX(CASE([type]) WHEN 'display' THEN value END) [display],
       MAX(CASE([type]) WHEN 'contact' THEN value END) [contact],
       MAX(CASE([type]) WHEN 'ship' THEN value END) [ship]
FROM <table> GROUP BY ID, Name
```

Result :

```
ID  Name    display     contact     ship
5   test    display1    contact1    ship1
6   test2   display2    contact2    ship2
```

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me

```
WITH T
AS
(
    SELECT
      id , 
      name, 
      type,  
      value  
      FROM table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b 
          ON a.id = b.id
        WHERE  b.type in ('display','contact','ship')
)
SELECT
  *
  FROM T
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX([Value])
    FOR
    [Type] IN
    (
        [display],[Contact],[Ship]
    )
  )PVT
```

Check the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/696e32/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you want `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[type] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([id], [name], [type], [value])
VALUES (5, 'test', 'display', 'display1')
      ,(5, 'test', 'contact', 'contact1')
      ,(5, 'test', 'ship', 'ship1')
      ,(6, 'test2', 'display', 'display2')
      ,(6, 'test2', 'contact', 'contact2')
      ,(6, 'test2', 'ship',  'ship2');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [type] IN ([display], [contact], [ship])
) PVT;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,name,[display],[contact],[ship]

from #b 

pivot(max(value) for type in([display],[contact],[ship])) As d
```

Comment: A code only answer does not provide much to the OP or anyone finding this answer. Please update your answer and expand on why you believe this answers the OP's question.

Comment: please look at [answer]